# Trouble with Kicad PPA install

Tags: package-management, software-installation, ppa

When trying to install `Kicad 5.0.2` from PPA, as recommended in 18.04, with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:js-reynaud/kicad-5
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kicad
```

I see strange effects, none of which are discussed at the Launchpad page.

- "*Help/Getting started*" gives an error. It is only available after running `sudo apt install kicad-doc-en`.
- After that install, it will open the file manager with the file marked, but not Firefox as expected. How can I change that? The page opens fine by double-clicking it in the file manager.
- The command `sudo apt install kicad-libraries` should install the symbol-, template- and footprint- libs. It did something, but they did not appear in the program. For example "*File/New/Project from Template...*" was empty. The templates appeared only after I installed `sudo apt install kicad-templates`
- After `sudo apt install kicad-demo` they can not be seen anywhere in the GUI. After a search I found them in `/usr/share/kicad/demos`. Is one really supposed to `sudo` copy them to the home directory and change all file permissions?

I crosschecked the Windows download for V5.0.3. There, everything installed, fully configured and ready to go. Why not in my Ubuntu? Tests were done on a fresh installation of Xubuntu 18.04.